# libフォルダに配置したcss,jsをapplication.{js,css}に読み込みたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

Ruby on Railsで管理画面を作っています。

デザインのためAdminLTEというテンプレートを使おうと思って、
Zipファイルをダウンロード、プロジェクト/libフォルダにダウンロードしたものを置きました。

ですが、このフォルダにあるcssファイルとjsファイルをプロジェクト全体に適用するために
以下の各プロジェクトへの設定方法がわからなくて困っています。

- `/app/assets/javascript/application.js`
- `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

libフォルダのcss, jsファイルを読み込む方法を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `1) lib ディレクトリの下に、どのように置いたのか`、`2) application.js にはどのように書いてみてダメったのか`を追記してください。`lib/assets/stylesheet/*` のようになっていない疑惑。

Comment: @user3758624 返事ありがとうございます。1) libディレクトリにはおっしゃる通りlib/assets/stylesheet/*のようではなく、lib/adminlte/bootstrap/js・css/*のようになっています。2) application.jsにはまだ何も書いていません。いつもgemしか使ってなかったため、何を書けたいいのか全然知らなかったからです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

とても良いページがあったので、引用します。

http://ruby.studio-kingdom.com/rails/guides/asset_pipeline

> プリコンパイルのアセットは、 app/assets、lib/assets、vendor/assetsの3つのうちのいずれかに置くことが出来ます。
>
> lib/assets/javascripts/moovinator.js
> マニフェストを次のように書くことで、参照します。
> //= require moovinator

よって、

`lib/assets/javascripts/adminlte/bootstrap/js/hoge.js` のように配置し、
`application.js` には、
`//=require adminlte/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/hoge` として読み込むと解消されると考えます。